# Combine columns, remove hyphen comma and space in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to combine values from two columns into one and then remove the colons, spaces and hyphens.

```
SELECT
documentation.nsma1_date + documentation.nsma1_time AS "Start Date"
FROM
documentation
```

This returns column Start Date with data 2021-01-20 09:09:00

I have tried to get it to return 20210120090900 without any luck. Any idea how to do this? I have tried the REGEXP_REPLACE and FORMAT but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_char()` from here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

```
--Assuming 2021-01-20 09:09:00 is timestamp

 select to_char('2021-01-20 09:09:00'::timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
    to_char     
----------------
 20210120090900
```

**UPDATE**

```
select 
  to_char(documentation.nsma1_date + documentation.nsma1_time,'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') AS "Start Date";
```

Comment: This is how to manually format it, correct? How do I get it to do it automatically? Sorry, just starting to learn Postgresql.

Comment: See UPDATE with what I think you are asking. If this is not,  then you will need to be more specific about what you want? If so provide an example as update to your question.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!